# SSD Died, Detected by BIOS but not OS

Tags: linux, ssd, hardware-failure, kali-linux

So few days ago I was playing a game. When I was finished with it, I closed the game and to my avail, everything was frozen (I could only move my mouse). I assumed silly Windows 10 simply crashed, so I force shutdown my computer by holding the power button.

I then started it. The BIOS was taking minutes to load, which was unusual. I assumed something might have happened with the motherboard, so I opened the laptop and went through the components, narrowing down the problem.

It ended at the 128GB Kingston mSATA SSD drive which, when removed, made BIOS boot instantly. The mSATA had windows and was not bootable, so I bought a mSATA to USB adapter and booted KALI up via USB.

When booted, I connected the SSD with the adapter to the USB hub and when running **lsblk** I get the following:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   450M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0    99M  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0    16M  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0 464.5G  0 part /media/root/BCB22D59B22D1A02
└─sda5   8:5    0   786M  0 part 
sdb      8:16   1    29G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   1    29G  0 part /lib/live/mount/medium
sdc      8:32   0 119.2G  0 disk 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
loop0    7:0    0   2.5G  1 loop /lib/live/mount/rootfs/filesystem.squashfs
```

The drive I am going after is **sdc**, which clearly does not have a partition. When running **lsblk -o MAJ:MIN,NAME,KNAME,FSTYPE,MODEL,SIZE,TYPE,MOUNTPOINT,STATE** I get the following output for my **sdc** drive:

```
8:32  sdc    sdc           SABRENT 119.2G disk                         offline
```

I used the "Disks" program included in KALI and it shows the [following information.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FOjY.png)

Almost everything I try leads me to "No such device or address found." error in linux. For example, when I try to create an image of the device via "Disks" program. Using Windows software to recover it is impossible since the drive is not recognized at all there.

Is there a way I can go about recovering my data?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you have the drive connected to the motherboard, does it eventually boot?  Does the BIOS recognize it at all?

Answer (score 0):

When lsblk shows the device, then the system known about it. I suggest to use the traditional fdisk program in order the examine existing partitions, if existing or to recreate such ones if not more existing. According to your information, the partition structure of your disk is lost. I ignore why.